# How to connect to a very old winCE PLC from external network?

Tags: networking, router, raspberry-pi, windows-ce

I have this old PLC running WinCE 3.0. It has IP 192.168.0.99 and TCP port 1200 so i can connect from PC. This works OK when i have both PC and PLC on the same network.

I would like to access port 1200 on the PLC but from an external network. I configured port forwarding on my router so port 1200 is visible from the outside but i ran into an issue. This old PLC wont accept incomming connections from ip addresses on a different network and this cannot be changed.

I need to access this PLC from an Amazon EC2 server in which i need to attach severl remote PLC like this one i mention. All PLC's locations have internet access through a router or a raspberry with a 3G usb dongle.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas you could provide me

Comment: Your could try setting up a VPN, or use remote desktop (eg VNC or TeamViewer) to connect to a computer on the intranet and access from there.

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct port forwarding? Port forwarding are rules that tell one device to route requests on a certain port to a specific LAN IP. I wonder how is it possible for the PLCs to traffic's origin...

Comment: hi @MichaelBay i have checked port forward several times and is OK. packets from external ip arrive to the router and are being redirected to PLC. It just doesnt accept ip addresses out of its range

Comment: As suggested by @AFH, a VPN is generally recommended and that's for security reasons. There's no reason for a device that can be accessed from within LAN not to work the same way from outside with proper port forwarding. Via mobile connections is a different matter if it goes trough SPI firewall. Dr. Google failed to find any other references to PLCs (or WinCE) not working with NAT except your own posts.

Answer (score 0):

your WinCE blocks router usually because of but not limited to:
1. blacklisted router ip address
2. blacklisted router mac address
3. blacklisted L2 / L3 switch port number

your winCE accepts connections from your pc usually because of:
1. whitelisted pc ip address
2. whitelisted pc mac address.
3. whitelisted L2 / L3 switch port number

They are few approach to test this scenario: 
1. Can you change your router's mac address to pc's mac address ?
2. can you change your router's ip address to pc's  ip address ?
3. do you have access to L2 / L3 switch between winCE computer and internet ?

I may have more questions but see if my replies above relevant.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. The software running on my WinCE machine is very limited and wont allow any changes to the firewall. I ended up connecting the PLC to a VPN